# Spark Metrics - csv sink not updating after initial update, unless pooling directory is cleared after every update

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am implementing spark metrics with a csv sink on a databricks cluster.

below is the metrics.properties config which I am using based on the metrics.properties.template [link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/conf/metrics.properties.template)

```
*.sink.csv.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.CsvSink

*.sink.csv.period=1
*.sink.csv.unit=minutes

*.sink.csv.directory=/dbfs/metrics_sink_csv_test/

worker.sink.csv.period=1
worker.sink.csv.unit=minutes
```

this works for the initial pooling, but post that no files are added or updated unless the pooling directory is cleaned.

([snapshot of metric files being added to pooling directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdwYM.png))

My assumptions are that every time the metrics are pooled they are added under same file name
and if the file already exists there is a file name clash and  the new metrics are not added.

Presently I run another spark job that continuous cleans the pooling directory.

Is there some way to avoid this ?

Can the metrics be appended to the existing files or new files be created in case of file name clashes ?

Comment: It's an old question but I am in the same situation - files are written for the first sink period, and no other files are added in the sink folder after that. The folder has to be cleaned then written to. This seems a bit clumsy.